# Owl Carousel Auto Height Recalculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Im trying to create a form wizard using owl carousel. I have some conditional javascript running to see what form elements get certain inputs.

For example, I have a number of select boxes that have yes or no answers and depending on which one you pick, it will show or hide other select boxes. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/eju2uw20/1/

Here is the code I am using for the Owl Carousel.

```
$('.consultationSlider').owlCarousel({

    singleItem:true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: false,
    navigation : false,
    pagination : false,
    autoHeight: true,
    slideSpeed: 800

});
```

If you click on the next button, you will see the autoheight working. However, when you click on the "please choose" select box and click "no", you will see another select box appear.

How can I make it so that owl carousel recalculates the height to make up for the added elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g23aqagv/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(function(){
 $(".owl-carousel").each(function(){
    $(this).data('owlCarousel').updateVars();
 });
},1500);

});
```

*Shorten the time for the update, but not too short.* This works in the stable version 1 release of Owl Carousel, I don't know about Owl2.

In your situation, you can do the following (as per @YeahMKD):

```
$('.websiteDeveloped').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'no'){
        $('.completitionDate').show();
        $('.consultationSlider').data('owlCarousel').updateVars();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'yes'){
        $('.completitionDate').hide();
        $('.consultationSlider').data('owlCarousel').updateVars();
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution works great. I edited the code a bit so that it wasnt on set interval. I noticed it was causing a weird flashing animation. I think this works very well as well.

Ill edit your answer with the updated code

Comment: I didn't approve the edit because others who want to update the slides may find the general approach more helpful since it's not specific. I added your js to the original answer.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer updates the code every few seconds using an interval which will increase the load and is not a clean solution.
This solution is much cleaner no need for extra code and only uses the function when needed...

```
setInterval(function () {
  $(".owl-carousel").each(function () {
    $(this).data('owlCarousel').autoHeight();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep, I agree. This should be the accepted answer. The answer above is not a clean solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

Owl carousel provides documentation on manipulating content within a slider be worth looking at.

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html

You will have to rebuild the slider if the select is ticked and a new select box is added.

Answer (score 0):

remove property this prperty `autoHeight:true,` from owl initilization